# Rcpp: error occured building shared library

Tags: c++, rcpp

I have a cpp code in a file named PSM.cpp as given below,

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<std::string> useInitLists() {
    std::vector<std::string> vec = {"larry", "curly", "moe"};
    return vec;
}
```

When I source the following code, I get following error.

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("PSM.cpp")
g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/Users/30708/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/Rcpp/include"  -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c PSM.cpp -o PSM.o
PSM.cpp: In function 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > useInitLists()':
PSM.cpp:5:60: error: in C++98 'vec' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'
PSM.cpp:5:60: error: could not convert '{"larry", "curly", "moe"}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >'
make: *** [PSM.o] Error 1
Error in Rcpp::sourceCpp("PSM.cpp") : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

Can someone please suggest what the error means and how to resolve the same? Thanks.

Comment: exactly what it says, `in C++98 'vec' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'`

Comment: if you can't switch to another compiler, you can try using [Boost.Assignment](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/assign/doc/index.html)

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov consider myself a noob in c++ and Rcpp. If I want to update the compiler, what should I do? Should I manually update the compiler on my computer, or there is another solution to this which Rcpp provides? Trying to understand, does Rcpp automatically installs c++ compiler on the computer, or it is a prerequisite for using Rcpp?

Comment: I guess, you're using g++ on a linux machine, so maybe adding the command line `-std=c++11` will work. Try that first, before considering 'upgrading'. Also, check the version by using `g++ --version`, 4.4+ [should do](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov no I am working on windows.

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov Do you mean using Sys.setenv("PKG_CXXFLAGS"="-std=c++11")? I am still getting the same error using this command as well :(

Comment: You can try the alternative `-std=c++0x`, but I never used g++ on Windows.

Comment: @Unda Post your answer as a solution, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the alternative `-std=c++0x`, but I never used g++ on Windows.

(Glad it helped !)

Comment: FWIW, the [compiler suite](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) here (as of this post) uses gcc 4.6.3, which does not have full support for C++11 -- some C++11 features are enabled through `-std=c++0x`, but `-std=c++11` does not work.